# Error while adding zeros to month and date columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have Date column values as 2020-6-10,2020-6-9 and so on. I need to add zeros if the number in month or date is below 10.
I tried the below code but I am getting an error. Can someone tell me I am getting it? Is there any better method. I need to change the values in the Date column.

```
for x in df['Date']:
    y,m,d = x.split('-')
    m = m.zfill(2)       
    d = d.zfill(2)
    x = y + "-" + m + "-" + d
```

Error  = not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Answer (score 1):

This error is saying that the split function isn’t giving you the three values you expect; year, month and date. If your input value of x isn’t what you expect then nothing will work.

I suspect that one of the values in your column doesn’t have the format y-m-d you expect. Or more precisely, it has fewer than 3 values split by “-“

Wrap the split function in a try except and print out the value to see what value of `x` is breaking.

```
try:
  y,m,d = x.split('-')
except ValueError:
  print(“This input does not split: %s”, x)
```

Once we’re sure of the inputs we can come up with a way to get the outputs you need.

Comment: That except statement is too broad. I would suggest only capturing ValueError. Otherwise, you may end-up try-catching other exceptions as well.

Comment: Thanks, will do as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when you try to split the string input at your second line.
It can be easily reproduced this way:

```py
>>> y,m,d='aaaaaa'.split('-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

You will need to add a try-catch block to capture those inputs that do not represent valid dates. For example:

```py
>>> try:
...     y,m,d='aaaaaa'.split('-')
... except ValueError:
...     return ''
```

You can also do some preprocessing to your Pandas dataframe before calling those statements:

```py
>>> df.dropna(subset=['Date'], inplace=True)
```

You can also fill missing values with a placeholder:

```py
>>> df['Date'].replace('', '01-01-2020', inplace=True)
```